# Application Scoping Filter Evaluated Incorrectly by Incremental Provisioning Cycle

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

I am using a scoping filter on top of users/groups to control provisioning to an enterprise app by following [this tutorial](https://hajekj.net/2023/09/18/entra-id-user-and-group-provisioning-with-bitwarden/).

To apply the scoping filter, I deployed a function app which syncs the value of a custom extension attribute on each user to membership in a specific security group called "Keeper Password Manager Users". The function executes every 5 minutes, and updates the extension attribute on users who are in the group to `true`, while updating the attribute on users who are NOT in the group to `null`.

Intended sequence of steps when a user is added to the group:

1. Function executes: attribute is set to `true` for user
2. Application provisioning cycle runs: scoping filter evaluates to `true` for user since attribute is `true` for the user
3. User is granted access to the app

Intended sequence of steps when a user is removed from the group:

1. Function executes: attribute is set to `null` for user
2. Application provisioning cycle runs: scoping filter evaluates to `false` for user since attribute is `null` for the user
3. User is deprovisioned from the app

All steps except steps 2 and 3 of removing a user from the group behave as intended. When I remove a user from the group, the function sets the attribute to `null` as intended, but the scoping filter still passes and thus the user is never actually deprovisioned from the app.

Scoping filter for the app:

[image]

Provisioning details of the app:

[image]

Code for the function app:

```
Import-Module -Name Microsoft.Graph.Authentication
Import-Module -Name Microsoft.Graph.Users
Import-Module -Name Microsoft.Graph.Groups
Import-Module -Name Microsoft.Graph.Applications

Connect-MgGraph -Identity -NoWelcome

# Name of the extension attribute
$extensionPropertyName = "extension_d21b98d1dac8483bad5684b1cc44ceb8_KeeperLicense"
# Security group object id
$keeperPasswordManagerUsersGroupId = "8e2ace19-422a-4d02-a5d8-1faf01a65777"

$tobelicensedUsers = Get-MgGroupMember -GroupId $keeperPasswordManagerUsersGroupId -All | Foreach-Object { ,$_.Id }
$keeperEnabledUsers = Get-MgUser -Filter "extension_d21b98d1dac8483bad5684b1cc44ceb8_KeeperLicense eq true" -All | Foreach-Object { ,$_.Id }

if ($keeperEnabledUsers -eq $null) { $keeperEnabledUsers = @() }

# Ids of users that need to be provisioned
$add = Compare-Object $tobelicensedUsers $keeperEnabledUsers | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' } | Foreach-Object { $_.InputObject }

# Ids of users that need to be deprovisioned
$remove = Compare-Object $tobelicensedUsers $keeperEnabledUsers | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' } | Foreach-Object { $_.InputObject }

# Update attribute to true for users that need provisioning
$add | Foreach-Object `
{
    $json = '{ "extension_d21b98d1dac8483bad5684b1cc44ceb8_KeeperLicense": true }'
    Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Method PATCH "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$_" -Body $json -Debug
}
# Update attribute to null for users that need deprovisioning
$remove | Foreach-Object `
{
    $json = '{ "extension_d21b98d1dac8483bad5684b1cc44ceb8_KeeperLicense": null }'
    Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Method PATCH "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$_" -Body $json
}

$groups = Get-MgGroup -All
# Groups that have been assigned to the application
$keeperUsers = $groups | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like "Keeper Password Manager Users" }
$projectGroups = $groups | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like "PG*" }
$filteredGroups = $keeperUsers + $projectGroups

$applicationObjectId = "ba0bd903-e02c-4bee-b2d8-1ae81c3d0a6c"
$userRoleId = "63a9859a-24d2-4d35-a412-b97549968424"

$existingAssignments = Get-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignedTo -ServicePrincipalId $applicationObjectId -All | Where-Object { $_.PrincipalType -eq 'Group' } | Foreach-Object { ,$_.PrincipalId }

$toAssign = $filteredGroups | Where { -not $existingAssignments -contains $_.Id }
# Provision users with the user role
$toAssign | ForEach-Object { New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId $applicationObjectId -ResourceId $applicationObjectId -PrincipalId $_.Id -AppRoleId $userRoleId }
```

My user account is not in the security group:
[image]

Function app executes successfully without errors:
[image]

Extension attribute is updated as intended by the function, as tested with the following command:

```
Get-MgUser -Filter "extension_d21b98d1dac8483bad5684b1cc44ceb8_KeeperLicense eq true" -All | Foreach-Object { ,$_.UserPrincipalName }
```

- My user account "anil.mawji@company.com" is not present in the list as expected

Provisioning logs reveals my user is "Skipped" when I should actually be deprovisioned, because Azure incorrectly thinks that the attribute is still set to `true` even though it is NOT.

[image]

My account is a member of a different group that is provisioned to the app, but this should not make a difference as my account does not satisfy the scoping filter. If I remove myself from all groups provisioned to the app, I am deprovisioned as expected.

So my question is - why is my account passing the scoping filter evaluation, and what can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I tried maintaining the true/null scheme while changing the scoping filter condition to IS NOT NULL instead. Unfortunately this did not see results, as the scoping filter was still passing after the provisioning interval.

Upon further investigation, it seems there is a known issue where [users are not always provisioned after coming back into scope via a group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/app-provisioning/known-issues?pivots=app-provisioning#member-of-group-not-provisioned:%7E:text=Member%20of%20group,are%20properly%20provisioned.). The inverse might also be true (users are not always deprovisioned when leaving scope of the group). This theory is consistent with what happens when I restart the provisioning of the app, as my user account is eventually deprovisioned.

I am hoping there is a more practical solution to this, as assuming I am correct, I do not want to have to restart provisioning every time one of my users is removed from the group.